# McDonald's Omega in SAS

Tags: sas

Many sources now recommend use of omega (as developed by McDonald, 1999) as opposed to alpha (Cronbach, 1951) to an estimate the reliability of a multi-item measurement scale.

In 2020, Hayes & Coutts (*Communication Methods and Measures, 14*(1), pp 1-24) provided macros to estimate omega in SPSS or SAS. However, at least as of SPSS28, SPSS has included an option to get omega, so the macro isn't needed. Does anyone know if there is a method to get omega in recent versions of SAS? It doesn't seem to exist as an option in PROC CORR. I've searched the documentation, and also googled it, but haven't found it.

(The need for this comes from the fact that as far as I know the macro requires the use of the raw data, and I would like to/need to enter the variance-covariance (or correlation) matrix.)

It would not be excessively difficult to get it by running a factor analysis and then calculating omega by hand, but I have to do it for many different scales, so it would be nice to simplify it as much as possible.

Comment: If you have a quesiton about how to implement an algorithm in SAS code then post the algorithm with enough data to demonstrate how it can work.  It is trivial to generate a correlation matrix from the source data if that is your quesiton.

Comment: @Tom What I am asking, as I stated, is "Does anyone know if there is a method to get omega in recent versions of SAS?" I don't need a correlation matrix: That is what I (will) have as input ("I would like to/need to ENTER the variance-covariance (or correlation) matrix.")

If SAS hasn't implemented a procedure for omega, then I will have to either write a macro (which I don't know how to do) or do it by hand.

Comment: Not sure why everyone is down-voting this question. I wish they would explain so I can edit to clarify.

Comment: If you have licensed the IML package with your SAS installation why not just use the macro you mentioned?  Are you sure that there actually is any algorithm that that can calculate OMEGA just from a correlation matrix? Did you read the papers that were cited as reference in the SAS code you pointed to so you can understand the algorithm it is implementing?

Comment: There's an Omega in GLM but I don't know enough to know if it's the same as what you're trying to calculate and don't have the time to do the comparison. https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-compute-omega-squared-in-sas-after-proc-glm/

Comment: This is not a coding question. As the closing request states: This question belongs on https://stats.stackexchange.com/. That's why you are getting downvotes.

Comment: @Wimanicesir
Over on Cross-Validated they say:
"if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here;" - but this isn't about statistical expertise. I have the statistical expertise I need. 

I need to know about the SOFTWARE: can SAS calculate this statistic with an input correlation/covariance matrix. 

I don't see anywhere until you that pointed out that this question belongs on stats.stackexchage.com

Comment: Looks like a coding question.  It would be better with example input data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about all of the functions of that macro, but the first simple example call can be re-created from a correlation matrix (at least a SAS correlation dataset that includes the N, MEAN and STD of the variables also).

So first convert their example CSV file into a dataset and run it through the %OMEGA() macro

```
data blirt ;
  infile 'c:\downloads\omega\blirt8.csv' dsd truncover;
  input var1-var8 ;
run;
%omega(data=blirt,items=var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8)
```

to get the expected output:

```
This estimate of omega is based on the factor loadings of a forced
single-factor maximum-likelihood factor analysis usings SAS's built-in FACTOR procedure.

                        Reliability:
                               Omega

                               0.785


   Item means, standard deviations, and estimated loadings
               Mean           SD      Loading     Error Var

  VAR1        3.365        1.012        0.663         0.583
  VAR2        3.379        1.037        0.642         0.663
  VAR3        3.156        0.936        0.576         0.544
  VAR4        3.133        1.001        0.711         0.496
  VAR5        2.976        1.071        0.549         0.845
  VAR6        3.237        0.981        0.643         0.549
  VAR7        3.379        1.142        0.376         1.161
  VAR8        2.664        1.003        0.398         0.847
```

So now let's try to recreate it.  So first make a correlation matrix.  Then run that through PROC FACTOR.  Then transpose the results.  Calculate the loading and error terms. And sum them up to be able to calculate the RELIABILITY value.

```
%let data=blirt ;
%let items= var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8;
proc corr data=&data out=&data._corr noprint;
  var &items;
run;
proc factor data=&data._corr nfact=1 method=ml outstat=&data._factor noprint;
  var &items;
run;
proc transpose data=&data._factor out=result name=varname ;
  where _type_ in ('MEAN' 'STD' 'PATTERN');
  var &items;
  id _type_;
run;
data result;
  set result end=eof;
  loading=pattern*std;
  err = (1-(pattern*pattern))*std**2;
  lambda+loading;
  err_sum+err;
  if eof then reliab=(lambda*lambda)/(lambda*lambda+err_sum) ;
  if eof then put reliab=;
  keep varname mean std loading err reliab;
run;
proc print;
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    varname      MEAN       STD      loading      err       reliab

 1      var1      3.36493    1.01160    0.66329    0.58338     .
 2      var2      3.37915    1.03663    0.64167    0.66287     .
 3      var3      3.15640    0.93564    0.57578    0.54390     .
 4      var4      3.13270    1.00068    0.71053    0.49650     .
 5      var5      2.97630    1.07101    0.54944    0.84517     .
 6      var6      3.23697    0.98114    0.64293    0.54927     .
 7      var7      3.37915    1.14157    0.37648    1.16144     .
 8      var8      2.66351    1.00264    0.39808    0.84681    0.78504
```